# Listbox in tk/tcl 2

Tags: listbox, set, tcl, tk-toolkit

```
#Variables:
set var1 123
set var2 456
set var3 789

#Widgets:
label .label1 -text ""
listbox .lstb1 -height 3 -width 20 -selectmode browse
.lstb1 insert 0 Var1 Var2 Var3

#Procedure
proc SelectionHappened {listbox label} {
set activeItem [$listbox get active]
$label configure -text $$activeItem
}

#Interface
bind .lstb1 <<ListboxSelect>> {SelectionHappened .lstb1 .label1}
grid .label1 .lstb1 -sticky news
```

How to get in .label1 value of the selected variable, not the variable name ?

ie: instead of "$ Var1" get "123"; instead of "$ Var2" get "456";  instead of "$ Var3" get "789"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
.lstb1 insert 0 Var1 Var2 Var3
```

to this:

```
.lstb1 insert 0 $var1 $var2 $var3
```

and this:

```
set activeItem [$listbox get active]
```

to this:

```
set activeItem [$listbox get [$listbox curselection]]
```

and finally this:

```
$label configure -text $$activeItem
```

to this:

```
$label configure -text $activeItem
```

(Why doesn't `$listbox get active` work? When you select an item in the listbox, `$listbox get active` gives you the item that was active *before* you clicked. If you select the same item twice, `$listbox get active` will point out that item the second time.)

---

Update in response to comment:

Leave this line

```
.lstb1 insert 0 Var1 Var2 Var3
```

as is, and change this line:

```
set activeItem [$listbox get active]
```

to

```
set activeItem [lindex {123 456 789} [$listbox curselection]]
```

or

```
set values {123 456 789}
set activeItem [lindex $values [$listbox curselection]]
```

Documentation: [label](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/label.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [listbox](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/listbox.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it works. But I would like that in listbox all lines were displayed in the form of names of variables as before.

Comment: Yeah! Its works! That's what I wanted! Thank you very much, Peter !!

Answer (score 0):

How about using the label widget's `-textvariable` option?

```
proc SelectionHappened {listbox label} {
    set varName [$listbox get [$listbox curselection]]
    $label configure -textvariable $varName
}
```

Comment: The list item text isn't the same as the variable name. I don't know if that's a dealbreaker.